# how to know recent code check-ins to the SVN repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to know about what are the list of files, which are checked-in to the svn repository recently in the eclipse IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the SVN Repository Exploring perspective, select the repository and choose "Show History" from the context menu. This will show the repository history in the History view.

Select one of the history revisions to see the list of changed files.